# Асинхронное выполнение нескольких задач

Tags: java, асинхронность

Есть две задачи которы мне нужно выполнить, эти задачи могут выполнятся параллельно, к примеру я хочу просто сделать `System.out.println()` в обеих задачах, но что бы продолжить мне нужно дождаться выполнения обеих задач. Нужен аналог из `JS` - `Promise.all()`. Я так понимаю мне нужно скорее всего `CompletableFuture` но как это реализовать не совсем понимаю.

Но в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) я не могу найти метод который принимал бы массив задач.

Каким образом я могу это реализовать?

Comment: [`allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-)?

Comment: @zRrr да, скорее всего это allOf() , но как это реализовать!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Runnable f = () -> {
    int delay = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(500, 3000 + 1);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch(InterruptedException exc) {}
    System.out.println("Done");
};

CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(f);
CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(f);
CompletableFuture<Void> future3 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(f);

CompletableFuture<Void> all = CompletableFuture
                                .allOf(future1, future2, future3)
                                .thenRun(() -> System.out.println("All done"));

all.get();
```

Comment: Похоже - это то, что мне надо, спасибо!